# Is it possible an xcode archive is corrupted without letting me know? WEIRD iOS 4.x behavior

Tags: iphone, ios, compiler-construction, ios4, app-store

I have an app on the iphone app store that has a very bizarre bug. It has to do with a user dragging an image around the screen. On iOS 5.x it works beautifully. On iOS 4.x it does not work (only lets you drag on a diagonal). The bug is disastrous because it prevents the user from continuing.

Anyways, there should be no reason why the code acts differently between 4.x and 5.0 (no deprecated methods were used or anything). And when I started testing for the problem I realized that the code I compiled and submitted to apple built onto my iphone actually works perfectly on 4.2.

So, the app store version of my app exhibits the weird bug explained above on 4.x and not on 5.0, but the app does not exhibit the bug WITH THE SAME CODE when built from xcode to my device. How is that possible? Could the compiler have messed things up?

---

**Resolved. This was the issue was with armv6 and the LLVM 3.0 compiler with CGPoints. See here: [Apple Dev Forum](http://devforums.apple.com/thread/122059?tstart=15)**

Comment: That **is** weird!!! Resubmitting wouldn't be possible either...you can drop an email to Apple and ask what's going on...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I might ask Apple, but I need to submit an update right away! Anyone on 4.x can't use my app at all basically. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that you uploaded a previous version of the code, if you're using svn, etc? I did that once XO...

Comment: no. but thanks anyways for the help.